# What encoding does [BouncyCastle] PKCS10CertificationRequest.getEncoded() return?

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography, bouncycastle

Does it return [DER encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) data, or some other format?

The [Javadoc](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/pkcs/PKCS10CertificationRequest.html#getEncoded()) I've been able to find leaves something to be desired details-wise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for v1.52, [`org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest#getEncoded()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.52/org/bouncycastle/pkcs/PKCS10CertificationRequest.java#PKCS10CertificationRequest.getEncoded%28%29) is implemented as:

```
public byte[] More ...getEncoded()
    throws IOException
{
    return certificationRequest.getEncoded();
}
```

This calls `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.CertificationRequest#getEncoded()`, which results in the inherited method [`org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Object#getEncoded()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.52/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Object.java#ASN1Object.getEncoded%28%29). This method actually has some Javadoc, and it states "Return the default BER or DER encoding for this object".

I wasn't completely sure whether this guarantees DER encoding, so I did the following:

```
private byte[] makeDEREncodedRequest(final PKCS10CertificationRequest request) {
    try {
        return request.toASN1Structure().getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ... <Exception handling code> ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume it *did* return DER? You don't say in the answer. I guess the reason that somebody downvoted is that you can expect a PKCS#10 defined certificate request to be returned when `getEncoded()` is called. That's what the class is there for. You only need to look at the PKCS#10 standard to see what's in it.